# Subclass RelativeLayout with secondary constructors in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm tryin to subclass RelativeLayout in Kotlin but I'm stuck with the three constructors.

```
public RelativeLayout(Context context) {}
public RelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {}
public RelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {}
```

I've tried the process described in http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5482057 but I don't see how I can match those to my use case.

Hoping that the three constructors called each other, I've tried to use default values but it crashes at app startup:

```
class SquareRelativeLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0)
: RelativeLayout(context, attrs!!, defStyle) {}
```

Any hint on the idiomatic Kotlin way to do this?

[edit] I'm using Kotlin 0.8.11

Comment: I have no idea about anything to do with Kotlin but you might want to look at the source for `RelativeLayout` at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java although you'll probably need to look at the source for `ViewGroup` as well as the three constructors don't call each other and directly call in to the `super` versions.

Comment: Yep that's right. My issue here is that Kotlin only allows you to have one constructor. There are some tricks (e.g., optional params, Factory methods) to circumvent this limitation but I have a hard time figuring out this particular case.

Comment: Can't you replace `attrs!!` by `attrs ?: someDummyAttrs`? I don't think that the linked discussion is of any use here.

Comment: Kotlin now has secondary constructors, use them: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Since M11 (0.11.*), you can use [*secondary constructors*](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors) to solve this problem.

Kotlin does not support more than one constructor (yet), so all you can do as a workaround is write this particular class in Java (you can freely mix Java and Kotlin in your project)

Comment: Update: Kotlin now supports [multiple constructors](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/03/kotlin-m11-is-out/) \o/